# Select from database based on multiple occurrences in junction table

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Could you help me with finding the right way of selecting from database some data – based on multiple occurrence in junction table?

Im using Sequelize ORM, but plain SQL also would be ok. Query should be dynamic – based on users input. Although, even static solution would be very helpful at this point.

I will use some example to better describe problem which im facing here:

I have two tables – lets say one for orders, and second for products (Order, Product).
Every order can contain multiple products, every product can be related with multiple orders. I made in sequelize Many to Many relationshop between those tables using order_product (OrderProduct) as junction table (which contains some additional fields other then IDs of order and product – e.g. amount of product):

```
Order.belongsToMany(Product, { through: OrderProduct });
Product.belongsToMany(Order, { through: OrderProduct });
```

My question is – how can i get from database all orders wchich contains – for example – product of ID = 1, AND product of ID = 2, AND product of ID = 3?

What will be most elegant solution using Sequelize or plain SQL?

I experiment with **include** statment in Sequelize, but i failed at using this correctly in this case.

On the other hand many 'EXISTS' statement in plain SQL (one after another) would be probably far too expensive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you would have a bridging table called something like `OrderProducts`.  Then you can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select op.orderId
from orderProducts op
where op.productId in (1, 2, 3)
group by op.orderId
having count(*) = 3;  -- number of product
```

If a product can be in an order multiple times, then use:

```
having count(distinct op.productId) = 3
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Your answer pushed me to the right direction. ;)